# solve $y'=ay+b$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this differential equation which I want to solve

$\displaystyle\frac{dT_i}{dt}=\frac{1}{RC}(T_a-T_i)+\frac{1}{C} \Phi_h$

I know it is in the form

$y'=ay+b$

But how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 8):

If you have $$y'(x)=ay(x)+b(x),$$for constant $a$, then the simpliest way is to multiply the equation by $e^{-ax}$ (nonzero everywhere) and deduce that 
$$(y(x)e^{-ax})' = e^{-ax}b(x),$$which implies that
$$y(x)e^{-ax} - y(0) = \int_0^x e^{-as}b(s)ds.$$
Finally,
$$y(x) = y(0)e^{ax} + \int_0^x e^{-a(x-s)}b(s)ds.$$

Comment: Reminds me of the Laplace transform.

Comment: Why solve an equation the OP didn't propose? And if so, why stop at $b(x)$? Consider $b(y)$ as well!

Comment: @JohnD calm down, please. From the initial question it is unclear whether $a$ and/or $b$ are constant or are functions of $x$. In my answer I used the case $b=b(x)$ because the proposed method still works and because it could be of help for other readers.

Comment: This is solving what the OP asked. He identified the general equation form, and this is just rearranging that. Therefore, I would say that you set up the answer to the question he asked, without getting bogged down in the specific terms he has in his equations. +1.

Answer (score 5):

As a separable equation:

\begin{align}
{dy\over dx}&=ay+b\\
{dy\over ay+b}&=dx\\
\int {dy\over ay+b}&=\int\,dx\\
{1\over a}\ln|ay+b|&=x+C\\
\ln|ay+b|&=ax+aC\\
e^{\ln|ay+b|}&=e^{ax+aC}\\
|ay+b|&=e^{ax}e^{aC}\\
ay+b&=\pm e^{aC}e^{ax}\\
ay+b&=De^{ax}, \quad D\not= 0\\
y&=Ke^{ax}-{b\over a}
\end{align}

You can also solve it via an integrating factor:

\begin{align}
y'-ay&=b \qquad\quad\therefore\text{integrating factor is }e^{\int -a\,dx}=e^{-ax}\\
e^{-ax}(y'-ay)&=e^{-ax}b\\
[e^{-ax}y]'&=be^{-ax}\\
\int[e^{-ax}y]'\,dx&=\int be^{-ax}\,dx\\
e^{-ax}y&={be^{-ax}\over -a}+C\\
y&=-{b\over a}+Ce^{ax}
\end{align}

Comment: The separation of variables can lead to many errors...

Comment: Any method done incorrectly can. Separating the variables is a perfectly legitimate method.

Comment: Indeed, it is a legitimate method. Yet what happens with your deductions when $ya+b=0$? Moreover, if $b$ is a function of $x$, then this method fails, too.

Comment: If $y'=0$, it isn't a differential equation so we don't undertake the method. Yes it fails if $b$ is a function of $x$. It also fails if $b$ is an elephant, too. But neither was asserted in the problem statement. The context indicates that $a$ and $b$ are constants here.

Comment: No, the problem here come from the fact that *a priori* when you make the first division, you can not guarantee that the denominator $ay+b$ is not zero - hence you need to use the argument along the lines of *given the initial data, we have a non-zero right hand side is some neighbourhood of initial data, therefore we can divide by $ay+b$* and only then you can make some integrations and finally prove that $ay+b$ is never zero.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{1}{a}\int \dfrac{dy}{y+\dfrac{b}{a}}=\dfrac{1}{a}\int\dfrac{d\left(y+\dfrac{b}{a}\right)}{y+\dfrac{b}{a}}=\int dx$$